# How to keep small rocks and stones out of hiking boots?

Tags: gear, hiking, boots, footwear

I keep encountering this issue during summer, when wearing short trousers or a skirt while hiking: my boots get filled up with small rocks and stones, and I must stop from time to time to empty them. I guess this is a common issue, but I was wondering: is there some method to avoid, or at least lessen the little stones which get in my shoes?

What I have tried so far:

- wearing long trousers which cover the boots (too warm)
- tying shoelaces differently (not too effective)
- walk on the grassy side of the road (not always comfortable)
- change the way I walk (hard and demands constant attention)
- trying to see whether it happens with other shoes/boots too (and it does... now I use a Lomer Pelmo)

Comment: Something like that will do it, won't be too hot: https://dirtygirlgaiters.com/

Comment: @Wills I think this is exactly what I am looking for :)

Comment: You will find gaiters of all sizes and shapes for all types of hiking being trails or snow on mountains. Here some examples. http://www.outdoorresearch.com/en/womens/gaiters.html

Comment: wear lighter pants? I wear pants in every season, up to around 30C

Comment: @njzk2 yes, I consider buying some extra light pants soon-ish

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like Russell said, gaiters are what you need, there are many varieties, most are meant to help keep your feet and pants dry while moving through the bush, but in your situation I'd probably recommend a pair of trail running gaiters:

[image]

They're built exclusively for keeping sand, dirt, and rocks out of your shoes, and they're pretty stylish, which is apparently kinda important for some girls... Check out  [Dirty Girl Gaiters](https://dirtygirlgaiters.com/)

Comment: See my comment ;)

Comment: @wills, didn't even notice your comment, you should have made it an answer!

Comment: I always thought these were "gators," but "gaiters" makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai People typically don't want any gators on their legs when they go out for a hike. They aren't the easiest to get off without your leg coming off with them.

Comment: And gators don't even do a great job of keeping rocks out of your shoes, because anything can end up anywhere once they're rolling you.

Comment: @ShemSeger the style doesn't matter - I wasn't aware of these lightweight gaiters, I have only the higher/heavier ones, and those are quite warm.

Comment: @Akabelle And note that these attach with a hook into your laces in front and velcro glued to the back of your boots rather than the typical under-the-footwear anchor, thus they can be much lighter.  Mine do not extend beyond the area covered by my socks, I don't notice any extra warmth from wearing them, just a lack of stones in my boots.

Answer (score 8):

The two answers suggesting the purchase of gaiters seem like a great idea.  The same effect can be gained with socks.  Either cut the elastic off of a pair of socks that are worn out.  Or just roll down the tops of long socks over the cuff of you boot/shoe.

If you don't own or wear long socks, and you know someone who wears nylons, ask them to give you any old nylons with runs in them.  You can cut them into gaiters of you own.

Comment: Rolling down the tops of existing socks works for gravel; for sand less so as the sand ends up staying around your ankle or working its way down inside the sock

Comment: @Chris, for thick socks yes, but if you had thin socks on, or sock liners, you could give them a twist as you folded them down and they'd essentially work the same as a trail running gaiter. So it depends on what socks you're wearing.

Answer (score 5):

Lightweight gaiters are your best option.  They do a very good job of keeping things out of your shoes.  If those are also too hot for you then you will have to reconsider the effort it takes to change your stride/walk so that you're not kicking up as much detritus.  It will come down to which is less inconvenient for you:  adding gaiters, changing your walk, or living with the rocks.

Answer (score 1):

While gaiters might be useful for many hikers, for me that is too high maintenance.

Instead, I choose where I hike to avoid the problem.  Steep hills "encourage" me to walk slowly and to carefully select where I place my feet on each step.  And staying on the main path (usually) has less loose debris to kick up.

Here was my choice two days ago in the Columbia River Gorge (Oneonta Gorge):
[image]

Comment: Sorry but your answer is not very useful. "Instead of buying a pair of gaiters ($30), hike on tracks that does not require such gear". Do you have a car? You need to put petrol, pay for maintenance. It might be better to sell it and walk everywhere.

Comment: @Desorder:  If you have a choice, you can hike where there is lots of stuff laying on the ground, or you can hike where there is not so much.  That is a direct answer to the question *How to keep small rocks and stones out of hiking boots?*   Perhaps I misunderstand the context of this forum?  Is it meant to support only equipment-intensive answers?

Comment: +1 for keeping it real (and for not being the 4th answer that suggests the same thing). Learnt how to hike, yo. *"Pick 'em up and set 'em down, Pyle!"

Comment: @wallyk Please note I didn't downvote your answer. I don't think we should support only _equipment-intensive answers_ . I actually think we get pretty creative answers here. I just think your answer is not practical even because you can get a pair of gardening boot cover at your favorite garden shop for as little as $5. Also think how many places people would miss out because "the track has too much gravel" or "The shrub was too dense"

Comment: Not that the price, $30 now reduced to $5, has anything to do with whether it's "high maintenance" or "equipment-intensive". You could be given a whole bunch of kit for free and it'd still be a whole bunch of kit.

Comment: @SteveJessop You can get a pair of hiking gaiter for $30 bucks or even some $5 bucks pair of gardening ones. The idea is to make the trip to the outdoors more enjoyable. It's not required to have some or all the gear and some people are just fine without it but the answer suggests to limit the outdoor experience. That is what I don't like in the answer.